# how to get a Pre-Authenticated request for an object in OCI object storage using python SDK?

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-python-sdk

I want to create pre-authenticated request for an object inside a bucket in the OCI object storage using python SDK. I found out that I can use get_preauthenticated_request for the bucket to put objects inside the bucket but not to get the objects pre-authenticated. I can create a pre-authenticated request using the OCI console but I need to do it in a python script. can anybody help me in this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `create_preauthenticated_request` ([see code](https://github.com/oracle/oci-python-sdk/blob/master/src/oci/object_storage/object_storage_client.py#L691)) for both buckets and individual objects.

The difference is in the access type:

- `ANY_OBJECT_WRITE` is for the whole bucket
- `OBJECT_READ`, `OBJECT_READ_WRITE`    and `OBJECT_WRITE` are for objects

So you should be able to create a Pre-Authenticated Request with something like

```
request_details = create_preauthenticated_request_details()
request_details.access_type("ObjectReadWrite")
par = create_preauthenticated_request("namespace", "bucket", request_details)
```

You can find more on the [request details here](https://github.com/oracle/oci-python-sdk/blob/master/src/oci/object_storage/models/create_preauthenticated_request_details.py) and for the [request itself here](https://oracle-cloud-infrastructure-python-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/object_storage/models/oci.object_storage.models.CreatePreauthenticatedRequestDetails.html).

Let me know if this works for you, I don't have an account to test against at the moment.